# How to include files in java ? Is it possible in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, include

Is it possible to include files in java source files somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking the answer is "no". What do you need it for?

Comment: Do you mean something like the #include directive in C? What would you need it for?

Comment: I generate java code for gwt which I would like to include in a gwt template.
I know there are other ways. I would just make sense if there were some include directive.

Answer (score 3):

You could of course use a preprocessor to create your source files from templates but that in general is not advisable and will create more problems than it solves.

Apart from that: no, Eclipse does not offer a way to do that. Including files in the source code is not The Java Way™. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not really, java doesn't work that way. If you need code from another class, you use

```
import package_name.classname
```

which will search for the class in your class path (that includes the currect directory). If you have jar-files that contains the classes you will have to add them to your class path with an argument to the java inteprentor

```
java -cp jarfile.jar:. your-class-file
```

In unix : is used to separate paths, in windows i think it is ;.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aspect to weave in intertype declarations and/or use pointcuts to weave advice to method declarations. This is not equivalent to #include, but the effects can be similar.

See this [AspectJ tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/EclipseCon2006/) for a starting point and the [quick reference sheet](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf) for more details.